# Unable to load default.aspx, 'App_Web_XXXX'

Tags: asp.net

I have done a project and it is working fine for me in local system but when i publish the website and uploaded through our site and checking the page i am getting the error as follows

`unable to load default.aspx, 'App_Web_XXXX'`

Can any one tell what the problem was

Comment: Please visit this post - http://forums.asp.net/t/1008517.aspx/1?Unable+to+load+default+aspx+page+remotely

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your project is using code-behind but has not been compiled, or is missing the dlls.